# phpbb preg_replace deprecated error

Tags: preg-replace, deprecated, phpbb

Hi I have recently moved to php 5.6 and am now getting some deprecated errors from a phpBB3 installation. The offending line of code is:

`$tpl = preg_replace('/{L_([A-Z_]+)}/e', "(!empty(\$user->lang['\$1'])) ? \$user->lang['\$1'] : ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', '\$1')))", $tpl);`

Can anyone advise on how to convert this to preg_replace_callback?

Comment: A great place to start would be if someone could explain what the existing code is doing - I'm finding the syntax very hard to follow. I think it means this: apply the preg_replace string to $user->lang[$1] if not empty or to ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', '$1))) if $user->lang[$1] is empty.

Answer (score 2):

I just managed to convert the expression to the new format, and I am not a php wizard, so I am a bit proud of it!
Here is what I have written to remove the error messages (bbcode.inc line 494):

```
$tpl = preg_replace_callback('/{L_([A-Z0-9_]+)}/', function ($m) { return (!empty($user->lang['\$m[1]'])) ? $user->lang['\$m[1]'] : ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', '\$m[1]'))); }, $tpl);
```

There is another similar line in bbcode.inc in line 370, that can be transformed in the exact same manner, but the one in line 113, I can't fix...

Obviously because the pattern comes from a variable, so it will take a little more to figure that one out.